# Why I am getting `incompatible types error`?

Tags: java, arrays, int, double, incompatibility

Here is the code:

```
double[] hundredElementsMillionArray = new double[10000000]; 

        for(double ii=0;ii<10000000;ii++){
            hundredElementsMillionArray[ii] = ii;
        }
```

I am getting following error:

> ### incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

though no `int` has been used in the code. Why is that so?

Comment: Your code will not compile since the index of an array never be an double.

Comment: I am not a java expert but double ii should probably be int ii.

Comment: Try this `int ii=0;ii<hundredElementsMillionArray;ii++` inside your for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index of an array is always an `int`, so `hundredElementsMillionArray[ii]` would require to cast `ii` to `int`, but since such a conversion may cause a loss of information, it's not allowed without an explicit cast.

This would pass compilation:

```
double[] hundredElementsMillionArray = new double[10000000]; 
for(double ii=0;ii<10000000;ii++){
    hundredElementsMillionArray[(int) ii] = ii;
}
```

This would also pass compilation :

```
double[] hundredElementsMillionArray = new double[10000000]; 
for(int ii=0;ii<10000000;ii++){
    hundredElementsMillionArray[ii] = ii;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the array index can not be `float` or `double` it must be `integer`
so you must `typecast` to `int` as `hundredElementsMillionArray[(int)ii]` or best solution would be you should use index variable as `int` type.